# How is this icon called and how can it be used for an operator?

Tags: python, interface

How can the arrow icon that is displayed when calling the scaling operator be used for my own operator?

[image]

Comment: @RobertGützkow I wanted to add this icon in my addon. So, it can't be done with python?

Comment: The drawing of this cursor is setup by `transform_draw_cursor_draw` in ([transform_draw_cursors.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_draw_cursors.c)) and as far as I can see this can't be used from the Python API.

Comment: Well, may be in the future...) Thank you anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

I know these to be 'relationship lines'. In this case it looks like blender is showing what origin your cursor is scaling around.

Comment: I thought he meant what is the official name for those arrows followed by the lines.

Comment: Ah! Well in that case I'd just say the scale icon.

Comment: It also appears during rotation XD.

Comment: You're right. The only difference being rotation curving in from North and South and scale being a linear line East and West.

Comment: Yeah. I can't come up with a proper name for it though :D